# Extension of power series to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, power-series, diagonalization

**Question**

Suppose $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k, c_k \in \mathbb{R},$$ whenever $\lvert x \lvert < r$, where $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is the radius of convergence.

Similarly, the series expansion of a matrix function $f(A)$ is the corresponding series that is $$f(A) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k A^k, c_k \in \mathbb{R},$$ where $A^0 = \mathbb{I}$.

Moreover, for a diagonalisable matrix $A$, we can use the series expansion of $f(A)$ (when it converges) to write
$$f(A) = P
\begin{bmatrix}
f(\lambda_1) & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & f(\lambda_n)
\end{bmatrix} 
P^{-1},$$
where $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

What conditions do the eigenvalues of $A$ need to satisfy for the power series expansion of the matrix function $f(A)$ to converge?

*Hint : Think about what it means for f(x) to converge.*

**My answer**

We know that, in order for $f(A)$ to converge,
$$P
\begin{bmatrix}
f(\lambda_1) & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & f(\lambda_n)
\end{bmatrix} 
P^{-1}$$
must converge.

It is trivial to see that both $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are always convergent, so the problem reduces to checking the convergence of
$$\begin{bmatrix}
f(\lambda_1) & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & f(\lambda_n)
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $f(\lambda)$ takes the form of a geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a r^k$ which converges when $\lvert r \lvert < 1$. Thus, it follows that, for $f(\lambda)$ to converge, we need $\lvert \lambda \lvert < 1$ and so, for $f(A)$ to converge, we need $\lvert \lambda_i \lvert < 1\ \forall\ i \in \{1, \dots, n\}.$

---

Whilst discussing this with my professor, I think he asked me to consider the convergence for a general series and not just the geometric series, but then he proceeded to retract his words and say that my working was alright. Thus, I would like to check with the community here whether my answer is correct. If not, then any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would think that if $f(A) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k A^k, c_k \in \mathbb{R}$, then the convergence of $f(\lambda_i)$ should relate also to the $c_k$, not only on the value of $\lambda_i$.

Comment: It is necessary that the series is convergent for every eigenvalue.  If  the radius of convergence of $\sum c_nz^n$ s  greater than $\max|\lambda_k|$ the series $\sum c_nA^n$ is convergent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Hi, I agree with you! Do you think my answer is correct then? Since I am thinking it is quite clear that the series is geometric and no other series would fit this form

Comment: If you are considering a particular series where $c_n $ is a constant nonzero sequence then the radius of convergence is equal $1.$ Hence a necessary and sufficient condition is $|\lambda_k|<1$ for all $k.$ The matrix does not need to be diagonalizable.